# How to listen for a message in websocket client in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, websocket

I am using the following websocket client example in my application as a utility:

```
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://<my url>",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

when I launch a particular url in browser, print will start coming. So here **on_message** will print the message. How can I use the message value in my application as this websocket code is a separate utility. I need to use python 2.7 . How can I listen to **message** from another python code?